# Apache mod_rewrite catch all (.*) does not work as intended

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

Following is an excerpt of my `httpd.conf`. I want to catch all unmatched requests at `[2]` and reverse proxy to `http://localhost:8585`. However, all links were sent to `http://localhost:8585/var/ww/html/`

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule testing/(.*) http://localhost:8585/mytesting/$1 [P,L] # [1]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:8585/$1 [P,L] # [2] Catch all Rule

</Directory>
```

Here are some test I tried and the result after rewrite

Good Result

`http://localhost/testing/` => `http://localhost:8585/mytesting/` [3]
`http://localhost/testing/goodOne` => `http://localhost:8585/mytesting/goodOne` [4]

Bad Result

`http://localhost:8080/testing` => `http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/testing` [5]  I expect `http://localhost:8585/testing`

`http://localhost:8080/` => `http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/` [6]   I expect `http://localhost:8585/`

The problem is obvious that the last `RewriteRule` prepended `DocumentRoot`(/var/www/html/) after the rewrite. Did I do something wrong? Or is this the intended behavior? And how can I fix/workaround this to have my expected result?

Output from `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel 2`

[3]

```
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] rewrite 'var/www/html/testing/' -> 'http://localhost:8585/mytesting/'
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] escaped URI in per-dir context for proxy, http://localhost:8585/mytesting/ -> http://localhost:8585/mytesting/
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:8585/mytesting/
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (1) [perdir /] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:8585/mytesting/ [OK]
```

[4]

```
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] rewrite 'var/www/html/testing/goodOne' -> 'http://localhost:8585/mytesting/goodOne'
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] escaped URI in per-dir context for proxy, http://localhost:8585/mytesting/goodOne -> http://localhost:8585/mytesting/goodOne
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:8585/mytesting/goodOne
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (1) [perdir /] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:8585/mytesting/goodOne [OK]
```

[5]

```
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] rewrite 'var/www/html/testing' -> 'http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/testing'
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] escaped URI in per-dir context for proxy, http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/testing -> http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/testing
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/testing
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (1) [perdir /] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/testing [OK]
```

[6]

```
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] rewrite 'var/www/html/' -> 'http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/'
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] escaped URI in per-dir context for proxy, http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/ -> http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (2) [perdir /] forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/
::1 - - [{date}] [xxx][yyy] (1) [perdir /] go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:8585/var/www/html/ [OK]
```

Comment: What happens if you take the rules out of the `<Directory>` directive? I don't see why they need to be in there.

Comment: @arco444, do you mean moving `[2]` after the `</Directory>` directive like the following?  I'm new to apache, what I did may not make sense.

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule testing/(.*) http://localhost:8585/mytesting/$1 [P,L] # [1]
    </Directory>   
    RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:8585/$1 [P,L] # [2] Catch all Rule

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression requires a "**/**" after "**testing**", if this is optional as your second example implies, update your regexp to reflect this, by adding a **?**, also it's good practise to use %{REQUEST_URI}  rather than an unnecessary **(.*) + $1** combo eg.

```
RewriteRule testing/?(.*) http://localhost:8585/mytesting/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost:8585%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```